# Passing a script and string over SSH

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a perl script with a string value over SSH but I can't get it to work.

My script looks something like the following:

**ssh user@linux /home/user/script.pl "value1 value2 value3"**

The script will execute but for some reason the only value that gets passed to it is value1 and not the whole string value. It think this is because the double quotes are getting dropped when it transmits over SSH?.

Can anyone shed some light on this?. Cheers.

Comment: Better to show us code.

Comment: you need to show the perl code so we can understand the problem.

Comment: Its not really a perl issue, I am actually running this code from a Control Language program on an AS400. I am using QSHELL on the AS400 to invoke a perl script on a Linux machine. The code looks like this: QSH CMD('ssh user@linuxserv /home/user/myscript.pl "value1 value2 value3"')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the initial set of quotes is expanded by the shell that's being used to invoke the command, so what actually happens is:

```
ssh user@linux /home/user/script.pl "value1 value2 value3"
```

ends up as:

```
/home/user/script.pl value1 value2 value3
```

when run from the remote system.

You need to escape the quotation marks so that it doesn't get parsed locally, before being interpreted on the remote side.

To escape the quotation marks you can do:

```
ssh user@linux /home/user/script.pl \"value1 value2 value3\"
```

Comment: Thanks Petesh, I suspect you are spot on. I will give this a whirl and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Usually easier to pass larger values like that as `STDIN` into the remote script. That way it won't get eaten or mangled by commandline parsers or shells along the way.